# Imported image as plane does not have accurate colors

Tags: color-management

I am trying to make a music video and import my logo (`.png`), however the logo does not have accurate colors (it has clear white background, but blender shows it as gray): [link to screenshot #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dIMp.png)

These are my material settings, I hope I have started correctly: [link to screenshot #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1tef.png)

The circle I created behind it is also a bit grayish, so there must be something basic I'm missing. [link to screenshot #3 with the circle behing the logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brtYa.png)

Switching the mode does not solve the color problem, as mentioned in the comments the background of my logo is still gray afterwards.

Solved: I needed to add/move the light on top (to face the planes) and re-insert the image in order to reset to default settings. Result: [link to imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVEfm.png)

Comment: Can you try using an Emission shader instead of a Principled shader? The Principled shader will accept shadow and reflect light, so white color will depend on environment lighting. Emission shader will generally help colors stand out and not darken/lighten with the environment lighting.

Comment: Where do I setup this shader?

Comment: Where do I "Set the View transfrorm from Filmic to sRGB (or "standard") in the color management section" ? I do not see this option - https://imgur.com/z4p3g85

Comment: Changing from filmic to standard or any other option did not change the colors at all

Comment: As you can see here: https://imgur.com/nbg2qLv the image also has sRGB color space. Still gray - https://imgur.com/qmLyIve

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: What is wrong with the images? You don't want the embedded for sure, because they are too big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are on the right track...

Switch from **Filmic** to **standard** but not on the image or material like you did.

I actually didn't realize you could do it image by image like that but I think you need to switch it on the actual world scene.

Look under the "Scene" tab where you switch from EEVEE to **Cycles**... at the bottom look for "Color Management" and "View Transform" then switch that from **Filmic** to **Standard**.